# How to properly use if...else statement in conjunction with a for loop?

Tags: arrays, loops, for-loop, if-statement

I have two arrays. I have to display both arrays and then find common integers within them. If there are any, display them. If there aren't display 0 or write an outpu

I have the for loops to do it, but since the else is within the loops, it loops that statement. How would I make it so it only displays that statement once? By the way, there are no common integers so that statement is displayed correctly... just looped for some reason.

```
static void PrintF(int[] MyNumbers, int[] OtherNumbers) {
  System.out.println("");
  System.out.println("The first array's numbers are "+(Arrays.toString(MyNumbers))+" and the second array's numbers are "+(Arrays.toString(OtherNumbers))+".");

     for(int i = 0; i < MyNumbers.length; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < OtherNumbers.length; j++) {
                if(MyNumbers[i] == OtherNumbers[j]) {
                    System.out.println(MyNumbers[i]);
                }
                else {
                  System.out.print("There are no common intergers between MyNumbers and OtherNumbers.");
            }
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: you get always        System.out.print("There are no common intergers between MyNumbers and OtherNumbers.");
           ?

Comment: Yes, the arrays are [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] and [11, 12, 13, 14, 15]. That code loops "There are no common intergers between MyNumbers and OtherNumbers."

Comment: that's correct ,what's the problem?

Comment: I only want it to display the system.out.print one time.

Comment: see answer.....

Answer (score 1):

use this code

```
  static void PrintF(int[] MyNumbers, int[] OtherNumbers) {
  System.out.println("");
  System.out.println("The first array's numbers are "+(Arrays.toString(MyNumbers))+" and the second array's numbers are "+(Arrays.toString(OtherNumbers))+".");
     boolean has = false;
     for(int i = 0; i < MyNumbers.length; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < OtherNumbers.length; j++) {
                if(MyNumbers[i] == OtherNumbers[j]) {
                    System.out.println(MyNumbers[i]);
                    has=true;
                }
            }
        }
        if(!has)
        {
         System.out.print("There are no common intergers between MyNumbers and OtherNumbers.");
        }
      }
  }
```